# How to get two max id from two different rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table customer table, i need get max ids from two different approvers with same request id

[image]

How can i implement this scenairo

Expected output.

```
id request_id approver_id
 2   1           2
 4   1           1
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses a join to a subquery to restrict to only the max rows you want:

```
SELECT ca1.id, ca1.request_id, ca1.approver_id
FROM customer_approved ca1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT approver_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM customer_approved
    GROUP BY approver_id
) ca2
    ON ca1.approver_id = ca2.approver_id AND
       ca1.id = ca2.max_id;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may also use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY approver_id ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM customer_approved
)

SELECT id, request_id, approver_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

You can apply GROUP BY on your columns request_id & approver_id and then select MAX(id) to get your expected output as below-

```
SELECT MAX(id),request_id ,approver_id
FROM customer_approved
GROUP BY request_id,approver_id
```

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, your code also working fine for me. thank you

Comment: I think this is the better solution.